# Close votes wrong

Tags: discussion

We've got a question [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/26956/elusive-etymology-false-cognate/27007#27007), which is gathering close-votes. These close votes all state the reason that the question is off-topic. That is incorrect! Okay, the question does not show any prior research or anything like that, and the answer is obvious to experienced linguists, but still it's not off-topic. It's kind of like that question we had about Edenics, which was being voted down because the theory is unpopular and discredited, even if that shouldn't mean the question deserved to be voted down.

If I could work out how to vote *not* to close it, I would. 
Is there anything we can do about this?

Comment: [I wrote earlier](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1745/2555) about how I see the difference between philology questions, which I vote to close as off-topic, and linguistic questions.

Comment: See also this discussion: https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1754/2555

Comment: Lack of basic research like looking up accepted etymologies in wiktionary or etymonline **is** a reson for down and close votes. I don't want to see this site being cluttered with crackpot theories.

Answer (score 6):

What you could do about it, for starters, is provide an argument that the question is actually on topic, rather than just asserting that the OT claim is wrong and incorrect. That means, you have to grant that there are such things as OT questions, including ones that have to go with language, and that specific one is not such a question. You have ample clear articulations of the reasons why such questions are OT, so you would need to show that the question at issue is a different kind of question.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do, you're already doing: posting on Meta and that's a good start.

If you think a community decision is wrong or the like, you need to explain why though, as user6726 correctly explained. Simply saying it is might not be enough.